# Start PHP Daemon from php script

Tags: php, curl, exec, daemon

lets say I have simple php daemon script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php -q
<?php

set_time_limit(0);

while(1){
  //do something here
  if ($something == "somethingelse"){exit;}
}

?>
```

And I want to **run it from another php script**. What's the best way to do it?
I've been using the curl for that as so:

```
$url = "url to php daemon file";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 1);
$not_important = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But I'm looking for a better idea, if there is one :).

Comment: For running it via a remote HTTP request, you'd also need `ignore_user_abort(TRUE)`. By default, Webservers will kill running scripts when the remote user disconnects. Your curl version would run the script for 1 second, then curl would timeout and disconnect, causing your script to die.

Comment: Make sure you mark an answer as correct this time, maybe more people will help you in the future!

Comment: @MarcB Ignore_user_abort is Off. But this curl script works for me.

Answer (score 3):

```
shell_exec('/foo/bar/myscript.php');
```

Comment: wouldn't it need to be `shell_exec('php /foo/bar/myscript.php');`? I'm not sure if it would work on all systems without prefixing the command with "php"

Comment: @PeteHerbertPenito, The shebang line is there, so this will typically work.

Comment: The #!/usr/local/bin/php -q line at the start tells it to execute this with php so no that is not required

Comment: @SarahPantry will this wait for the results or just start the php file and continue with code after it?